# How to Add "Help" text for the particular field on Infopath form?

Tags: infopath, help

I just need to have a "Help" text popup when we mouse-over the field.

Answer (score 1):

1. Double Click on the Field to open the field properties.
2. Select Advanced tab and view the screen tip field.
3. Add the screen tip you want.

Follow [this](http://johnliu.net/blog/2011/11/10/infopath-managing-lots-of-tooltip-in-your-browser-form.html) for step by step instructions.

Comment: Thank You for your response!

Yes, currently I am using the Same ( Screentip)but apart from this is there any popup help text field we can have?

Comment: No that is not possible.